# save emacs user activity to disk

Tags: events, emacs, save, focus, buffer

I would like to move much more of my office work into Emacs.
I want to append the following information to %APPDATA%\log.csv file each time when I save buffer,
move focus to another application / buffer or quit Emacs

- timestamp (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) TAB event(saving, closing, focus) TAB
  location (p.ex. line number in buffer but the best would be the text
  in current branch entry of org-mode file )  EndOfLine

other processes record similar information to the same file so appending
to the file must be sure warn in case of a problem.
Anything specifically for that would be great help.

I currently have two issues that I give at the end of this text.
emacs stores information using the following code

```
(defun monthly-log-file ()
(interactive)
(let ((monthly-name (format-time-string "%Y%m")))
(find-file (expand-file-name (concat (getenv "AppData") "/OooData/log" monthly-name ".csv")))))

(defun append-string-to-file (string filename)         
"Appends STRING to FILENAME."                        
(interactive)                                        
(append-to-file (concat string "\n") nil filename))

(defun save-log-after-save-hook ()
(setq user-test-file
(expand-file-name (concat (getenv "AppData") "/OooData/log" (format-time-string "%Y%m") ".csv"))) 
(append-string-to-file (mapconcat 'identity 
                (list (format-time-string  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" (current-time))
                  "emacs" buffer-file-name "fix org branch") "\t") user-test-file ))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'save-log-after-save-hook)

(when (>= emacs-major-version 24.4)
(add-hook 'focus-out-hook 'save-log-after-save-hook))
```

But sometimes recording is not possible and I get the following warning:
opening output file: permission denied, c:/Users/jerzy/AppData/Roaming/OooData/log201509.csv

when saving from OpenOffice I am using 4 loops, which virtually eliminates any similar situation

```
sub appendTextLigneToFile(s$)
'calls: fnGetLogFileUrl
Const CN = "appendTextLigneToFile"
dim CRLF : CRLF = chr(13) & chr(10)
dim EOL : EOL = chr(10)

dim sURL$ :  sURL = fnGetLogFileUrl

dim sfa as object, tos as object
sfa = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.ucb.SimpleFileAccess")
tos = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.io.TextOutputStream")
dim size&
if FileExists(sURL) then size = sfa.getSize(sURL)
dim stream
dim i&
for i = 0 to 3
on error resume next
stream = sfa.openFileReadWrite(sURL)
if not isEmpty(stream) then exit for
on error goto 0
wait 500
next
if isEmpty(stream) then goto ExitWithInfo
dim ios as object
on error goto errorhandler
ios = stream.getInputStream()
ios.skipBytes(size)
tos.setOutputStream(stream.getOutputStream())
'oOutputStream.setEncoding( "UCS2" )
ios.setEncoding( "UTF-8" )  '
tos.writeString(s & EOL)
errorhandler: 
If (err <> 0) Then MsgBox Error, 16, CN
on error Resume Next
if not isNull(tos) then tos.closeOutput()
if not isNull(ios) then ios.closeInput()
If (err <> 0) Then MsgBox "obj closing problem", 16, CN
Exit Sub

ExitWithInfo:
MsgBox "File " & convertfromurl(sURL) & " is locked and timeout was exceeded.",48
end sub
```

I'm not a lisp programmer  but I'm trying to resolve the following two issues:

- modification of the function append-string-to-file when writing to the file to eliminate possible problem with permission denied (of course if the file is not longer blocked)
- get some text from branch line when in org-mode to pass it to above mentioned function

Comment: Show us the code you've already tried, and show us how it doesn't work. SO isn't a code writing service.